# How to Rotate foscam in iOS application?

Tags: ios, ipad, stream, rotation, ip-camera

I am working on foscam IP camera and I am unable to find any way to rotate the cam. I am successful to get the view of camera in my app successfully. I am using UDP classes. here is the code that i am using

```
- (NSURL *) getURL:(NSString *)forPage {
    return [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"http://%@/%@user=%@&pwd=%@",self.host,forPage,self.username,self.password]];
}

-(NSURL *)getVideoStreamURL{
    return [self getURL:@"videostream.cgi?"];
}
```

In my view controller

```
[cameraWebView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[frontCameraClient getVideoStreamURL]]];
```

Now kindly guide me how could I access the tools of camera to rotate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is to use the decoder_control.cgi:

```
Name: decoder_control.cgi
Permission: operator 
Syntax: /decoder_control.cgi?command=[&next_url=] 


Parameters value description 

0 up 
1 Stop up 
2 down 
3 Stop down 
4 left 
5 Stop left 
6 right
7 Stop right 
… Reserved 
25 center 
26 Vertical patrol 
27 Stop vertical patrol 
28 Horizon patrol 
29 Stop horizon patrol 
… Reserved 
94 IO output high 
95 IO output low
```